# Creating a bitmap from char* buffer MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm working with an unsigned char *buffer that contains an image (16bit grayscale). I'm attempting to load this buffer into a HBITMAP so that I can use SetBitmap on a picture box control to show a live stream of images in memory.

I've tried this so far:

```
HBITMAP memBMP;
memBMP = CreateBitmap(1080,1280,1,16,pBuf);
mPictureBox1.SetBitmap(memBMP);
```

Unfortunately the dialog box goes blank for a brief moment and then displays the buttons and elements again after iterating through all the images in memeory. Any suggestions would be much appreciated; I tried exhausting my google resources, but I couldn't find a clearcut example of how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Windows bitmaps do not support 16-bit greyscale images

Comment: You probably want to use `CreateDIBSection` to get a block of memory use can access directly as memory or use/display as a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn everything you need to know about CreateDIBSection from this MFC sample app. But you will have to compress your 16-bit data to 8-bit grayscale.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31/A-DIBSection-wrapper-for-Win32-and-WinCE